# Can an Akka anonymous actor access self?

Tags: scala, akka

Can an Akka anonymous actor have access to self? In my particular case I'm wondering if I can reply back to the sender with code similar to this (does not compile due to self not being found):

```
val xmlLoader = Actor.init {
    println("xml loader started")
} receive {
    case LoadResource(url) => {
        try {
            val xml = XML.load( URL("content.xml") )
            self.senderFuture.foreach(_.completeWithResult(xml))
        } catch {
            case e => self.senderFuture.foreach(_.completeWithException(e))
        }
    }
    case _ =>
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first of all, thanks for using Akka, hope you're enjoying it!

I'd recommend:

```
actorOf(
new Actor {
 def receive = { case "foo" => self.reply_?("bar") }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Viktor, I was suspecting that the anonymity of the actor was the problem. Thanks for the clarification. And yes, I'm liking Akka a lot ;)

Comment: Cool, have fun and happy hAkking!

Comment: How about: def actor(act: PartialFunction[Any, Unit]) = actorOf(new Actor { def receive = act }).start()

Comment: In 2.0 you have: def actorOf(f: ActorContext => Receive): ActorRef, (start is not needed anymore)

Comment: raichoo: In your suggestion you do not have access to self.

Comment: `actorOf` from which class? As of akka 2.3.x `ActorSystem.actorOf` doesn't work

Comment: @kostya Try `context.actorOf(Props(new Actor{
      override def receive: Actor.Receive = ???
    }))`